July 2024 Photo Contest: Flowers
The topic is "flowers", so photos containing at least one flower. All the way from one flower to a massive field of flowers is great!
The contest will end at the end of July (UTC time). The following rules apply (credit to Willeke, but slightly modified):

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
If you have people recognizable in the photo, you must either (a) have their permission to post the photo or (b) make them unrecognizable.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.
If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics.
Also, you can join us in chat to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.



Here is a lovely, but stinky example of a flower from a carrion plant known as Stapelia Gigantea. The flowers usually have five points. This is a rare six pointed example and is about nine inches wide. It is not native to Hawaii, but grows wild in the dry hilly areas of Waianea, Hawaii. That's where this picture was taken in the autumn of 2021.

This is the highest voted post at the end of the month.

I took this picture in Guadalajara. June 11, 2022.



The New York Marble Cemetery, the city's first non-sectarian burying place, is normally closed to the public. But you can visit a few weekends per year, as I did when I took this picture, on May 5, 2024.

Wild Carrot, Bishop's Lace etc.
A roadside wildflower photographed by me in UK in July 2024.
There is a single central purple flower in the clusters of small white flowers.


That's the famous japanese Sakura (AKA cherry blossom). I was lucky to visit Japan during the cherry blossom season (a small period between March and April) and see those stunningly beautiful flowers all over the country.
In the background we can see the Todaiji Temple.
Photos taken in April 2024, in Nara, Japan.




Portmeirion, Wales. July 2017:

Livingston, Scotland. June 2021:

Pennyhill, England. May 2022 (with bonus bee):


While riding my velomobile today I really noticed some of the flowers.

This is a low dike called Zevenmaat, close to Assendelft and I think part of that municipality. Under the trees you can see the flowers in the verges.

This is one of the flowers, I am not certain of its name but have been told once one nickname is Queen Anne's Lace.

And this is what they look like in a group, some still in flower and some already in seed.
All three photos taken today, 19 July 2024, near Assendelft, the Netherlands

Three photos of flowers, all taken by me in southern England.


Finally, these three from Gibraltar Botanic Gardens, 2022. Flowers really are a great subject to impress beautiful colors even at a very amateur stage like mine. On that day there was a very good sun light also!







Photos taken 1 April 2024, in Hortus Bulborum, Limmen, the Netherlands.
In this garden they grow heritage bulbs of many kinds of spring bulb flowers. The flowers are on show when they flower, some are early, some late, I was in the middle of the season. In these photos I have missed out many empty plots.

Congratulations on winning the virtual prize this month!

Three more flowers photographed by me in UK in July 2024.

Buddleia – or 'butterfly bush'



Roadside wildflower I'm unable to accurately identify – there are several.



The last thistles of summer still harvested by bees.



Glad I hadn't posted this here! This is between the back of Sannat and the cliffs in Gozo, in early April 2023, it should be exactly this point. I took this one with my Samsung A50 phone.


Last week I was walking with my mom in Rimini (Italy) and when we passed by this hedge she asked me to take "good" pics of roses and agapanthus. I like to take photos of flowers and when the light is good some colors really rock!



Beautiful tulips in a jar wrapped by Norwegian flag style ribbon. As you might have guessed from the cutlery and napkins, the picture was taken in the cafeteria at my workplace in Oslo, Norway.


When was this photo taken? Date (or at least year) should be included.
